# Open logical channel

Tags: applet, javacard

I try to open logical channel 1 from channel 0:

```
-> 00 70 00 00 01
<- 01
<- 9000
```

but i receive 6A86

`-> 00 70 00 01 00
    <- 6A86`

my question is :  what is the right command  to open the channel 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ISO 7816](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx#chap6_16), the MANAGE CHANNEL command structure is:

```
CLA  = 0x00
INS  = 0x70
P1   = 0x00 (for channel opening, 0x80 is for closing)
P2   = logical channel number (0x00 means the channel number is chosen by the card)
Lc   = empty
Data = no data
Le   = 0x01 if P1P2=0x0000, empty if P1P2 != 0x0000
```

The last line explains, why your command is wrong. You should use

```
-> 00 70 00 01
<- 90 00
```

instead. The reason why there is no output data is simple: you specified the channel number explicitly in `P2`, so there is no need to inform you what channel was used.